# Suppress Termcal Class Numbering

Tags: formatting, numbering, termcal

I'm interested in suppressing the termcal class numbering. My Googlefu showed me that I can use the code

```
 \newcommand{\calprintclass}{\textbf{\small\theclassnum}}
```

to change the formatting of the numbering, but I am unsure how to flat out remove it.

Working example for you fine folks to play with!  Thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{termcal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\patchcmd{\endcalendar}{[l]}{[c]}{}{}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\newcommand{\TRClass}{
\skipday % Monday (no class)
\calday[\textbf{Tuesday}]{\classday} % Tuesday
\skipday % Wednesday (no class)
\calday[\textbf{Thursday}]{\classday} % Thursday
\skipday % Friday (no class)
\skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
}

%%%%%\newcommand{\calprintclass}{\textbf{\small\theclassnum}}%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{calendar}{06/01/2015}{8}
    \setlength{\calboxdepth}{0.65in}
    \TRClass
    \caltexton{1}{}
\end{calendar}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `termcal` mixes the code itself with the instructions, which can sometimes be a bit confusing.  In the code of the package, the macro `\calprintclass` is defined (this is the command you mention in your question.)

So to change it (to anything) you need to use `\renewcommand` not `\newcommand`.  In your case you want to eliminate it altogether, so:

Just add:

```
\renewcommand{\calprintclass}{}
```

to your preamble.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! That works like a charm!!!  =)